# Send mail with Javalet: How can I find out which mail caused the Error

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am working on a Javalet which sends mails to different Addresses.

Sending mails to existing addresses is working fine.
The xxx@xxx.xx pattern is already tested in the form with an regex and tells the user if the mail is ok or not.

But if the user types a valid mail, but which does not exist, the sending fails, of course.
(And throws an `SendFailedException`)

Is there a way to give the user an error message which tells him what mail caused the error?
(the one which followed the xxx@xxx.xx pattern but did not exist)

Or is there any other way to test if a valid mail exists?

Thank you very much for your help (-:

edit:
for sending the the mail I use
`void javax.mail.Transport.send(Message arg0, Address[] arg1) throws MessagingException`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to test if a valid mail exists?

You can't do that in a sensible way. Many developers are trying too hard to validate e-mail adresses, and even the regex you use is probably too much already. The format of e-mail adresses is not exactly fixed. And, even if you would test for the existence of a mail account by sending a mail to it, you don't even know if it belongs to a person.

> Is there a way to give the user an error message which tells him what mail caused the error?

I'm not familiar with `javax.mail` specifically, but the function you call throws an exception. Why not do something like:

```
try {
    javax.mail.Transport.send(myMessage, myAdresses);
}
catch(MessagingException ex) {
    System.out.println("An error occured: " + ex.getMessage();
}
```

But maybe with better reporting. Also according to the documentation, the [`SendFailedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/SendFailedException.html) subclass (catch this one) has `getValidUnsentAddresses` to get you the addresses to where the sending of the message failed.

Comment: See also [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr).

Comment: @BillShannon good find. But as I already mentioned, validation on such level is not possible and my answer is the closest he'll probably get.

Comment: The point is, you're not always going to get an exception, but when you do you can get this information from the SendFailedException as you describe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am already using exception handling like the one above. I only thought it would be nice to tell the user which address caused the err. Eg. when I send a mail via MS Outlook to an address which does not exist or does not receive the mail I get back an errormail which tells me which adress could not be sent to. I thought that maybe there is something which can be done to implement that in the javalet as well, ...

Comment: @user3336766 no, that's not possible afaik. The mailserver sends these emails, MS Outlook doesn't really know about failing to send the message. Also those delivery failure mails are like any normal mail, you would have to analyse the body to know if it is a failure, and you can't really do that reliably.